# Storing Data Without Knowing Anything About the User

Tags: encryption, authentication, cryptography, web-browser, privacy

Let me start by stating that this is really my first foray into encryption.

I have written username/password systems, and such, and am familiar with salting and hashing passwords... but I have never really done anything with encryption.

I have an idea for a system that I want to build... and I have (what I believe to be) a clever solution for storing the user's data without knowing anything about them... but I am not sure if I am opening the door to some kind of "promise not to peek" flaw.

My idea is this: I want to be able to store encrypted information without knowing anything about the user.

The design in my head is this: the user sets up an account (username and password). An encrypted blob, keyed with the password, is created client-side (secret-key encryption via libsodium in JavaScript). The username is hashed (client-side... perhaps salted with the password?). This hash and the encrypted blob are sent to the server, where they are linked together in the database. When the user next logs in, the hash is sent to the server and the encrypted blob is sent back to the browser, where the password is used to decrypt the blob. All of this, obviously, happening over HTTPS.

Is there a flaw here? Am I overlooking something?

I want to be able to respond, even to a government subpoena, with "I don't know. And I can't find out."

Of course, malware on the client-end would be a problem... but I haven't been able to think of any way around that... and that isn't the issue I am trying to address right now. I just want to figure out a way to store customer information without know anything, at all, about my customers.

Comment: The payment question should either be removed or posted as a separate question, imho. Welcome to Security.SE!

Comment: sorry about that... that was more a stream-of-consciousness aside than an actual question.

Comment: Your system will offer no support for forgotten usernames or passwords. This is problematic.

Comment: You present a proposed solution without stating the problem you are trying to solve. This makes evaluating your proposal difficult.

Comment: I've edited for clarification

Comment: I am OK with being unable to address forgotten usernames/passwords... that is something that I would be upfront about. Basically, I am just offering anonymous storage.

Comment: If I was worried about government interference to the point of server manipulation then I would offer this as a product. Take a raspberry pi for example, attach a decent sized USB stick and program it to act as a LAN-based web service, then make copies and sell them. That way you aren't in control of any information at all and legally they shouldn't be able to bother you.

Comment: I still don't understand your requirements. For example, is knowing how many files each user stored, how big they are, when they uploaded them, and maybe more details like this ok? Is that included in not knowing anything about your customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of consistency I'll call the infrastructure operator (you) *Bob*, the client *Alice*, and the personalized government *Mallory*. This answer only describes a very simple attack for the government scenario, ignoring other aspects of your service.

The setting is as you describe: Bob operates infrastructure on which Alice stored an encrypted blob. Alice's access occurs through an application delivered by Bob via HTTPS.

Mallory has the resources to force Bob to cooperate in any way, and wishes to get access to the content of the encrypted blob stored on Bob's server.

To do so, Mallory changes the application Bob delivers via HTTPS in a way exposing the encryption keys (depending on Mallory's resources in some way that is not easily detectable - some months should be sufficient). Remember, Mallory is in possession of Bob's credentials, and thus can serve them properly. Mallory will receive the key the next time Alice uses Bob's service. Using the key, Mallory now decrypts the blob and does the happy dance.

The scenario is [not unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavabit), if Mallory really wants Alice's data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I guess that I was hoping to avoid a situation where Mallory wants Alice's information, by not having a record that Alice has an account. Is there a way around this? Or am I shooting for something that is completely undoable?

Comment: At least in America, I think it would take quite extreme circumstances for a government agency to be allowed to install malicious software on non-suspect computers. The example you mention was for server-side intrusion, not client-side.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Obviously, we can argue on whether the government is allowed to do so, but that is a completely different issue ;) - note that all it takes is to inject some JS into the server-side, it does not have to be *installed* (as in Alice's computer is permanently affected) - at least for lawyers I don't see why it should be handled differently. Also, remember that Alice is a high-value target in the scenario given. Everybody else is collateral damage (or could get filtered out in the unlikely event somebody actually cares).

Comment: @NathanPinkerton We are assuming a government-level attacker. Obviously such an attacker can identify each IP-Address, even the dynamic ones. So they can be sure that the target (whose information they want) exchanged *some* information with you.

Comment: @dst... you are right, and I hadn't thought about it from that (obvious) angle... tunnel vision, I guess. I was stuck on the issue of avoiding storing anything that could be personally identifiable on its own. I guess I need to do some more thinking/reading/researching.

Comment: This theoretical vulnerability applies to every application. Theoretically speaking, there is no way to be 100% certain that you are completely secure in that aspect. If this is a legitimate threat, then personal (private) servers should be used to host the content and clients should use a strict set of manually installed CA certificates. Even then you'd still have to worry about the theoretical possibility of software manipulation. If everyone worried about all of these theoretical vulnerabilities nothing would ever be built to begin with.

Comment: Why is this a problem @nathanpinkerton? You state you don't want to know anything about your customers, not that you want to be protected against measures such as these. Your requirements are still unclear to me.

Comment: @JonathanGray This problem does not apply *to the same extent* to applications which are not deployed on each use. Feel free to provide an answer based on your own opinion, which is - at least that seems to me - currently quite popular. I personally do not consider it a only theoretical vulnerability, given the scenario given in the question (targeted government-level attacks), but that, of course, is subjective ;)